# Datepart within a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a query that searches for instances of a particular column not being null within a query, and then breaking it out by month. That works fine, but I also need to add a subquery that joins another table and finds instances of another column within it. Here's the query:

`SELECT
    DATEPART(MONTH, CreatedDate) AS TheMonth,
    COUNT(CreatedDate) AS NASCL,
    COUNT(SQL_Date) AS NASQL,
    COUNT(Demo_Completed_Date) AS NADEMO,
    COUNT(Converted_Date) AS NAOPP,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(lead_load.Converted_OpportunityId)
        FROM lead_load
        INNER JOIN Opportunity_load
        ON lead_load.Converted_OpportunityId = Opportunity_load.Id
        WHERE Opportunity_load.Stage_Name = 'Closed Won') AS NACONV
    FROM lead_load
    WHERE Region='North America'
    AND LeadSource NOT IN ('Advertising', 'Trade Show', 'Social', 'Partner', 'Organic Search', 'Paid Search', 'Direct', 'Referral')
    AND CreatedDate > '2014-07-16'
    GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(MONTH, CreatedDate);`

The problem is if I try to put `DATEPART` into the subquery, it errors out because I'm not grouping it or aggregating by it, and the result just totals all instances of `Opportuunity_load.Id` where `Opportunity_load.Stage_Name = 'Closed Won'` for all time.

How do I make that next step and break this out by month, as I have the others?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, move your subquery into another nested query:

```
SELECT * 
    ,(SELECT
        COUNT(lead_load.Converted_OpportunityId)
        FROM lead_load
        INNER JOIN Opportunity_load
        ON lead_load.Converted_OpportunityId = Opportunity_load.Id
        WHERE Opportunity_load.Stage_Name = 'Closed Won') AS NACONV
FROM (
  SELECT
    DATEPART(MONTH, CreatedDate) AS TheMonth,
    COUNT(CreatedDate) AS NASCL,
    COUNT(SQL_Date) AS NASQL,
    COUNT(Demo_Completed_Date) AS NADEMO,
    COUNT(Converted_Date) AS NAOPP,
  FROM lead_load
  WHERE Region='North America'
    AND LeadSource NOT IN ('Advertising', 'Trade Show', 'Social', 'Partner', 'Organic Search', 'Paid Search', 'Direct', 'Referral')
    AND CreatedDate > '2014-07-16'
  GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, CreatedDate)
) tmp;
```